# Fill Many to Many field through API

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement an API to add **Agent**. The Agent has *Many To Many* field, **Role**.

I am using Django and Django Rest Framework.

Here is the models :

```
class Role(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    labe = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.labe, self.code)


class Agent(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    role = models.ManyToManyField(Role)
```

So I created Serializers :

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    role = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
            many=True, read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Agent
        fields = ['email', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'role',
                  'phoneNumber',  'experienceWorkYeares'],
        

    def save(self):

        agent = Agent.objects.create(
            email=self.validated_data['email'],
            firstName=self.validated_data['firstName'],
            lastName=self.validated_data['lastName'],
            phoneNumber=self.validated_data['phoneNumber'],
            experienceWorkYeares=self.validated_data['experienceWorkYeares']                
            role=self.validated_data['role'] // One of my multiple try but doesn`t work.

        )
        agent.save()

        return agent
```

How can I retrieve the role I sent via Postman and put it in the agent ? for the role I am POSTing role = "CODE1".

Thank you so much in advance.

*Basically what I am trying to do is : For each Agent there one or more role. I trying a lot of thing and I follow documentation but I am not able to do it.*

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `role` field should not be declared in the `Meta` class but in the `ModelSerializer` directly:

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     
    role = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)    

    class Meta:
         model = Agent
         fields = ['email', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'role',
                   'phoneNumber',  'experienceWorkYeares'],
         extra_kwargs = {
             'password': {'write_only': True},
         }
```

Then, if you want to write a ManyToManyField you should use something like:

```py
my_role = Role.objects.get(pk=self.validated_data['role'])
agent.role.add(my_role)
```

Another thing you could do is add a `validate_role(self, value)` method in your serializer that checks if the primary key provided is correct, and returns  `Role.objects.get(pk=value)` -- then you would get the Role instance in your `validated_data`. See [this part of DRF doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated the post.

I don't want to write a Role. In front I am sending a role code ("CODE123") to fill in Agent. And I don't know how can I get the Role with code CODE123 to put in Agen.

Comment: Ok right I get it. You cannot write a ManyToManyField directly. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/). You should get the role instance with `my_role = Role.objects.get(pk=self.validated_data['role'])` then add it the field with `agent.role.add(my_role)` (after `agent` is created).